# Connect Windows clients to a Windows Server 2012

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

My company has switched to a **Windows 2012 Server** recently, and we faced **domains** for the first time ever (we were using workgroups prior to this change, with a plain old **Windows XP** serving some shared folders). With the new server, my boss wanted to also give each user a logged access level to some folders (which I expect to make them work), so we need to connect them and use the user's credentials. However, some clients are **XP**, and some other are **Win7**, so I guess the "domain" part is a little away from my power.

Is there something I missed, and could you guide me through the process on connecting these clients to the server? What are the steps to add them to the **Active Directory**? Should I (definitely) upgrade XP to at least Win7?

Comment: You really need to get someone in there who knows what they're doing.  Hire a consultant... shouldn't be too expensive for a simple Windows domain setup.

Answer (score 1):

As the very basic steps you would need install the Active Directory Services role on a server and then configure it to start a new forest and a domain.
Then you would run domain join procedure from client computers. You can do that from both XP and Windows 7 machines. Then things are up to your needs.

I suggest you to search for some step-by-step guide which are plenty on the internet.

Try this one.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12370.step-by-step-guide-for-setting-up-a-windows-server-2012-domain-controller.aspx

Still, if you have someone to consult with - go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, upgrade all XP to a supported operating system NOW!

Comment: That's a horrible answer for something I'm sure the OP already knows. Upvoting anyways because it's true.

Comment: Are you sure? I quote: `Should I (definitely) upgrade XP to at least Win7?`

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/end-of-support.aspx  End of Life Support ended last month. Not much you can argue with about that. Now I know a few consultants who are still supporting XP machines but those are for very special circumstances. Otherwise, yes, if you had to choose a different operating system, Win-7 is the preferred OS over Vista or Vista 2.0 (Windows 8).

Comment: Why is Win7 preferred over Vista and 8? This is mainly opinion based, but I think we can agree that it should at least be supported by the vendor.

Comment: From what I have personally seen and experienced: Vista is not even an option, it is universally horrible and other administrators will think less of you if you use it (semi-kidding), Windows 8 is actually kind of nice once you get used to it and appreciate the new features, nonetheless, I think the main problem with the adoption of Windows 8 is that a lot of administrator manageability features have not really been improved so much as they have been "move around". I think a lot of administrators and knowledgeable decision makers suspect that Windows 8 will go the same way as Vista.

Comment: Windows 7 wins by default.

Comment: That's still opinion based. I wouldn't use Vista in a million years personally, but I'm quite happy with Win 8.1. Anyways, nothing to be discussed here :)

Comment: Oh yes, absolutely opinion based. I was going to write a disclaimer that it was purely opinion based but I hit the character limit for the last comment. :) Nonetheless, that is what I have been noticing in my local industry as the general "trend". Honestly, I think after 8.1 a lot of things have been changed around enough that I am open to administration of a purely Windows 8 network, but no clients have actually seen windows 8 and windows 7 side-by-side and said to me "Windows 8 is what I like more"

Comment: Also, if you're going to make the jump from XP the changes will be perceived by the end user as "less drastic" from XP --> 7 than XP --> 8